# Rewriting every occurrence of pattern in query string via mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have queries of this form going towards my server:

```
http://my.host.com/moo?p=1&s=2&targetURL=http://foo.com/sub/more/query
```

What I need to do is replace a part of the parameter of this query, specifically I need to replace `http://foo.com/sub/` with `http://bar.com/`, preserving all the other parameters in this query and also preserving the parameters of `http://foo.com/sub/more/query`. I would be content with just replacing it in `targetURL`, so I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/moo
RewriteRule ^/moo(.*)targetURL=http://foo.com/sub(.*)$ http://other.host.com/moo$1targetURL=http://bar.com$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^/moo(.*)$ http://other.host.com/moo$1 [L,R]
```

But the first query just never matches. Any help?

**EDIT**: To make clear, I have this:

```
http://my.host.com/moo?p=1&s=2&targetURL=http://foo.com/sub/more/query
```

and I want it to become this:

```
http://other.host.com/moo?p=1&s=2&targetURL=http://bar.com/more/query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.host\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)targetURL=http://foo.com/sub/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^/?moo$ http://other.host.com/moo?%1targetURL=http://bar.com/%2 [L,R=301]
```

You need to match the `targetURL=http://foo.com/sub/` part from within the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable using a `RewriteCond`. The query string isn't part of the URI when a `RewriteRule` matches against it. You can then use the `%1` and `%2` back references to reference the groupings matched in the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this version which i tested and works for me.

```
<i> 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.host\.com/moo [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p\=1\&s=2\&targetURL\=http\:\/\/foo.com/sub/more/query$ [NC,OR]  
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://other.host.com/moo?p=1&s=2&targetURL=http://bar.com/more/query/$1 [R=301,L]
  </IfModule>
```

Comment: No, this is not it at all. The URL I need to rewrite is in the `%{QUERY_STRING}`, as I had stated above.

Comment: Still not clear. This is part of your question i zoomed into " specifically I need to replace http://foo.com/sub/ with http://bar.com/". What's the request that comes to your server? to what do you want re-write to

Comment: As stated above, I have this: `http://my.host.com/moo?p=1&s=2&targetURL=http://foo.com/sub/more/query` and I want it to become this: `http://other.host.com/moo?p=1&s=2&targetURL=http://bar.com/more/query`